# How to append ellipse for the data dispalyed using ng-material-multilevel-menu

Tags: angularjs, truncate, cpu-word, ellipse

I am using ng-material-multilevel-menu for displaying the contents of the side menu as shown below

[image]

Here for the item Compatibility with Installed CS license is truncated and shown as Compatibility with Installed CS i.e any words which has more character is truncated should be shown as "word"+....

Please let me know is there a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add your customized class in configuration for classname key where you can extend .label[_ngcontent-c11] class with below css :

```
text-overflow : ellipsis;
overflow : hidden;
```

[image: example tried]

Comment: @Dhanalaxshmi, did it helped?